# Order text and numbers column

Tags: powerbi

I have a column with text and numbers in PowerBI that I want to order like this:

```
Date
J1
J2
J3
J4
J5
J6
J7
J8
J9
J10
J11
```

But when I try to order like that (Alphabetic order) the result is this one:

```
Date
J1
J10
J11
J2
J3
J4
J5
J6
J7
J8
J9
```

How can I solve it for J2 follows J1 instead of J10? I think the same problem happens when there are only numbers, the 10 after 1 but I would like the 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract some "sortable" information from your data. This depends on the format of the data. If the prefix is always the same (`J` in this case), you can delete it and convert the rest to a number. Or if the prefix can be different and it is important for the sorting of the data, then you can pad the number suffix with leading zeros to make them all with the same width (e.g. `J0001`, `J0002`, ..., `J0010`, `J0011`). Add a [custom column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column) with this sortable information and use [Sort by column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column) to define the sort order.

So in Power Query Editor add one of these custom columns:

```
Number.FromText(Text.End([Date], Text.Length([Date]) - 1))
```

[image]

to get the suffix as a number (make sure the type of the column is `Whole number` - change it if needed), or:

```
Text.Start([Date], 1) & Text.End("00000000" & Text.End([Date], Text.Length([Date]) - 1), 8)
```

[image]

to pad the numbers with leading zeros (to 8 digits in this case - this depends of the range of the numbers in your data).

At the end, you will have another column like these:

[image]

Then go to your report, select `Date` column in the fields pane and use `Sort by column` to define how to sort the data and choose the custom column you just added:

[image]

After that, when you sort by this column, it will use your custom column to get the defined sort order:

[image]